# Getting a table to stretch to the edge while inside of another table?

Tags: html, css

Trying to get two tables to always display next to one another, but it wouldn't be ideal to condense them into one big table. Currently my code is set up like this:

```
<table style="margin:0;padding:0;cellspacing:0;cellpadding:0">
  <tr>
    <td>     
      <table style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;cellspacing:0;cellpadding:0">
        <caption>Table 1</caption>
....
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;cellspacing:0;cellpadding:0">
        <caption>Table 2</caption>
....
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, the tables are leaving gaps in their respective cells and not stretching all the way to the border. This results in something like this 
[image]
You can see on Table 1 (on the left) where there's still space to the top and bottom, tho Table 2 is working perfectly. How do I eliminate this space and get the table to stretch to the border of the cell?